# Which model (in R) should I use for the data I have?

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis, model

I am having trouble determining what statistical test I should apply to my data - I'm new to statistical analysis and modelling. **Goal**: The influence of “ground cover” and “distance to water” on nest site selection (whether an area is a den site or not).

1. Response variable: nest area - i.e. whether the datapoint is a nest or is located within 100m radius of a nest. Binary 0/1 for No/Yes - I have “nest buffers” and randomly selected “non-nest buffers” (datapoints that are not nests and do not have nests in their 100m radius)

Independent variable:

2. ‘Distance to water’ (this variable is only relevant for the datapoints that are nests - i.e are the centroids of the buffers) - it is measured in metres.
3. Ground cover type (this consists of all datapoints within the buffer, including the centroid) - it is a factor made up of 4 levels: “N”, “Ni”, “F”, “A”.

The other data I have that I expect may affect the outcome (i.e. are confounding) include:

4. Groups (individuals are within groups that are restricted to their own territories. Each datapoint will be labelled as one of 27 groups. Some groups have more data than others).
5. Breeding season (e.g. 2015-2016; 2016-2017; etc., up to 2020-2021)
6. Location (there are two locations - “WAT” and “SAM”, i.e. a binary 0/1)

I am under the impression I have to do two different models for the independent variables, as ‘Distance to water” uses only a subset of datapoints from “ground cover type”.

I wanted to do a binary logistic regression with all 6 variables, but I’m confused as variable three and four have multiple levels - is a multilevel logistic regression better? Any advice about the correct model to use to investigate which variables affect whether a site is a nest site or not would be very welcome!.

[image: example data]

Comment: You can do logistic regression by converting variables with multiple values by converting them to one-hot representation.  In words, you will create a variable Group_OLO, which equals one if and only if Group="OLO" and so on.

Comment: Does this mean the logistic regression will be run on each and every group, rather than the the variables 'Group' as a whole?

Comment: No, this means you estimate the effect of each group within the same model.